# Почему значение счетчика цикла переданное в метод setTimeout всегда одно и тоже

Tags: javascript

Кто может объяснить, почему выводится 10 раз число 10, а не по порядку. Я знаю, что таймер сначала добавляется в очередь, а потом не знаю, что происходит

```
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
     setTimeout('alert(i)', 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Узри области видимости в js юный падаван. Такой вопрос задавался на этом сайте 100500 раз и я ща даже поищу где на него уже отвечали.

Comment: Собственно идете по ссылке выше и читаете подробный ответ на почти точно такой же вопрос.

Comment: Не печалься, @DivMan, я тебя выручу :) `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { setTimeout('alert(' + i + ')', 1000); }`

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том что функции, добавленные в setTimeout, попадают в конец очереди выполнения. Сначала выполнится тело цикла и вся логика и только в конце будет вызвана функция alert(i). Естественно что к тому времени цикл будет закончен и переменная i будет содержать 10

Рекомендую к прочтению  [данную статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script)